# Where can i still download Magento 1.4 sample data?

Tags: magento-1, sample-data

There is no 1.4 sample data i can download, i had tried to install the sample data 1.3 found from the below link and page, the file name is `Magento-sample-data-1.1.2-2015-02-12-09-16-25`. But after installed Magento 1.4, there is a blank page in browser.

https://www.magentocommerce.com/download#download1759

Anyone can help?

Answer (score 0):

1. Check permission and enable developer mode in index.php for displaying errors, For the cause of blank page.
2. You can find the sample data with structure [here](http://inchoo.net/magento/magento-archive-database-dumps-structure-only-data-only-full/)

Hope it helps.